# Parse Facebook logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions (Swift)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0, parsefacebookutils

I have set both Parse (1.7.1) SDKs and Facebook(v4) SDKs successfully, set bridging header files and AppDelegate.swift. Now in my ViewController, I am trying to create a Facebook Login and I am trying to use the code given in ['Parse iOS Documentation - Facebook SignUp & Login'](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS).

```
  PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, {
     (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
       if let user = user {
        if user.isNew {
           println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        } else {
           println("User logged in through Facebook!")
        }
       } else {
         println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
```

However when I paste it in my ViewController.swift > ViewDidLoad, I am receiving this error:

```
- Extra argument in call      // for { at the first line
```

Can anyone please help me sort this out?

Edit: The script given has worked for me in terms of syntax, however, now I keep getting "Uh no. The user cancelled the Facebook login." even before it asks for permissions; while the facebook page is still loading..  And the user I am trying is already accepted for this particular app. 
Take a look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b47G.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work-around by adding this code in ViewDidLoad:

```
   if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)

    }
```

together as placing in the button:

```
   @IBAction func Facebook(sender: AnyObject) {

    var permissions = ["public_profile"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

                self.facebookButton.alpha = 0



                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUp", sender: self)

            } else {

               println("User logged in through Facebook!")

                self.facebookButton.alpha = 0

                 let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)

            }

        } else {

            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")

            println("User cancelled")

        }


    }
```

Also in App Delegate:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Parse.setApplicationId("###",
        clientKey: "###")

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()


    return true
}
```

And

```
      func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

Bridging Header:

```
  #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
  #import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
  #import <Parse/Parse.h>
  #import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
  #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

I don't know how far it is true but it solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me when I upgraded to swift 1.2. Appears to be related to some kind of more restrictive syntax check with the new compiler. This change works for me:

```
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was about to start thinking the problem was related to me.. Probably, there is a problem on Parse documentation & Swift 1.2

Comment: Just to be clear, you replaced

     PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, {
     (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

with

        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

This is working just fine for me with swift 1.2

Comment: The syntax is working fine now; however I got "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." in the console even before the Facebook Login page is opened (before I get directed to the Facebook page in Safari). Just to make clear, my code is placed in the ViewDidLoad

Comment: t is working for me. Can you delay the call? I have a the call linked up to a button. I noticed that you are automatically logging in (which should be fine). I think there are a few other login bugs with the latest release. For example, I'm experiencing this too : developers.facebook.com/bugs/1139436116081834

Comment: Great! I wonder if what you were experiencing with the "auto-login" scenario is related to the bug I posted in my previous comment?

Comment: Do you get this: [Error]: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.7.1)?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact error, but the token I got back was Nil.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to your case but I placed "        PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()" just below the Parse.setApplicationId in App Delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but the code worked for me after changing it into:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Comment: The syntax is working fine now; however I got "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." in the console even before the Facebook Login page is opened (before I get directed to the Facebook page in Safari). Just to make clear, my code is placed in the ViewDidLoad..

Comment: Is this any different from my answer?

Comment: No. I said the syntax is working, so the app is not crashing. The problem is that I get 3rd condition, which is "Uh no" part. Apparently, [here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126952/parse-login-with-facebook-does-not-work?rq=1). Is your one working fine and you get the user logs in?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've been following this issue most of the day.

Comment: The first answer on Senty's reply had the solution for me: this needs to be within the scope of an IBAction to work (it won't work in viewDidLoad).

Comment: @doovers check my answer that i have added