# PFFacebookUtils login background cannot convert value to PFUserResultBlock

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parse-platform

With the following code:

```
@IBAction func FBLogin(sender: AnyObject) {

        @IBAction func FBLogin(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(self.permissions){
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("Login Canceled")
        } else if user.isNew {
            NSLog ("user signed up and logged in through FB")
        } else { NSLog ("user logged in through FB")
        }
    }   
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> "Cannot convert value of type '(PFUser!, NSError!) -> Void' to the expected argument type `PFUserResultBlock` ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting indicates the type signature for your result block does not match the expected signature. In particular, take a look at the types of your parameters (`user`, `error`). They are both implicitly unwrapped optionals (`!`). The correct type is optionals I believe (`?`). See this answer for more detail:
[Parse Facebook logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586120/parse-facebook-logininbackgroundwithreadpermissions-swift)

Also see the official samples in the documentation:
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users