# Getting Error with PFAnonymousUtils.logIn

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, authentication

The Code below returns an error:

> Cannot Covert value of type '(PDUser!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PFUserResultBlock'

```
 PFAnonymousUtils.logIn{ (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user != nil {
                    println("Success")
                }
            } else {
                println("Failed")
            }
        }
```

I looked at a few examples below for reference to see if there was a solution:
(1)[Parse Facebook logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586120/parse-facebook-logininbackgroundwithreadpermissions-swift)

(2)[PFFacebookUtils login background cannot convert value to PFUserResultBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849780/pffacebookutils-login-background-cannot-convert-value-to-pfuserresultblock)

(3) [iOS Developers Guide](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#anonymous-users)

Comment: thanks! I added a few edits, will post my solution after testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So With some help here's a complete solution:
Taking a suggestion where I would have to place :

```
PFAnonymousUtils.logIn{ (user, error) in
```

over

```
PFAnonymousUtils.logIn{ (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void
```

the next error would be this line:

```
if let user = user {
```

where the compiler assumes that this isn't an optional, so the final solution in code would be

```
PFAnonymousUtils.logIn{ (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Success")
            }
            else {
                print("Failed")
            }
        }
```

This way, it checks for an error, if there is an error, the code will print a line indicating as such.

Answer (score 2):

The type inference is being thrown off. Try without the types. So PFAnonymousUtils.logIn{ (user, error) in This might fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently fixing this! greatly appreciated!